# POST request timing out on request to APN server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apple-push-notifications, http2

I'm trying to set up Apple Push Notifications through a Rails back-end. I'm using the [NetHttp2](https://github.com/ostinelli/net-http2) gem to create the connection and jwt to sign my tokens.

Here's a sample of the responses I get when trying various combinations of post requests. I get a quick response if I omit the "authorization" header, and similar if I give it garbage or a fake token. But if I use the actual token that I've encoded, the connection times out. I have no idea what Apple is doing on the back-end - I get no message at all.

```
    [22] pry(main)> request = client.call(:post, '/3/device/adknerulkdf2345nl', 
body: "{ 'aps' => { 'hello' => 'hello' }", headers: {  "apns-topic" => "something" })
    => #<NetHttp2::Response:0x007fbee8226c90 @body="{\"reason\":\"MissingProviderToken\"}", @headers={":status"=>"403", "apns-id"=>"690A959F-27F0-5B5C-1173-0316D6CE4C91"}>
    [23] pry(main)> request = client.call(:post, '/3/device/adknerulkdf2345nl', 
body: "{ 'aps' => { 'hello' => 'hello' }", headers: { 'authorization' => "bearer garbage", "apns-topic" => "something" })
    => #<NetHttp2::Response:0x007fbeebbbf060 @body="{\"reason\":\"InvalidProviderToken\"}", @headers={":status"=>"403", "apns-id"=>"8EF335C7-1F05-1D99-5425-CCF200960626"}>
    [24] pry(main)> request = client.call(:post, '/3/device/adknerulkdf2345nl', 
body: "{ 'aps' => { 'hello' => 'hello' }", headers: { 'authorization' => "bearer snwekrwunlsdfu.sdlfknweru.awepi234np2", "apns-topic" => "something" })
    => #<NetHttp2::Response:0x007fbee7f38f88 @body="{\"reason\":\"InvalidProviderToken\"}", @headers={":status"=>"403", "apns-id"=>"C3B48281-C7F1-22B0-6159-0FD0B79C1D43"}>
    [25] pry(main)> request = client.call(:post, '/3/device/adknerulkdf2345nl', 
body: "{ 'aps' => { 'alert' => 'hello' }", headers: { 'authorization' => "bearer #{token}", "apns-topic" => "something" })
    SocketError: Socket was remotely closed
```

How do I debug this? Is there a way to view what is happening on the Apple server?

If not, has anyone set this up and has some tips? Honestly, I am not at all sure I am properly encoding the JWT token. I am attempting to use my p8 token from Apple and am using the 'ES256' settings but I don't know how to validate it. If I make another request with my token + garbage, it also hangs forever.

Here's the rest of the relevant code:

```
client = NetHttp2::Client.new("https://api.development.push.apple.com:443", 
{ connect_timeout: 100000})
token = JWT.encode({'alg': 'ES256', 'kid': APNS_KEY_ID}, 
(OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new @p8key), 'ES256', 
{'iss': TEAM_ID, 'iat': DateTime.now().to_time.to_i})
```

## After much heartache, the solution

I'm still not totally sure what was going on with Apple, but the answer was with my token encoding. The proper format is:

```
  token = JWT.encode(
    {
      "iss": TEAM_ID,
      "iat": DateTime.now().to_time.to_i
    },
    private_key, 
    ALGORITHM,
    header_fields= {
      "alg": ALGORITHM, 
      "kid": APNS_KEY_ID
    }
  )
```

It seems if you give Apple *something* with the format `authorization => bearer WHATEVER` it will hang forever trying to authenticate.
The JWT library is very particular about order and keys (as of 6/29/17).